# Python pyodbc settings

Tags: python

I am looking at a system that is using PyODBC and FreeTDS with a connection similar to the following:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=srv;DATABASE=dbtable;UID=uid;PWD=pwd')
```

I was wondering if after this connection is made, if it is possible to view the settings that are actually used. We dont currently have access to look at the configuration files

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information do you need?

You can get many information using `getinfo()` (wrapper for `SQLGetInfo()`):

```
db = pyodbc.connect('DSN=northwind')
isolation = db.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DEFAULT_TXN_ISOLATION)
print('isolation=%s' % isolation)
```

Have a look at `pgtests.py` for more `getinfo()` usage examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for connection settings, such as charset, FreeTDS Version etc